# Sign blackberry application with phonegap ant tool

Tags: blackberry, cordova, code-signing

I want to sign my blackberry application with ant tool of phonegap, so I can try it on my device.

I made the 2 signature file (sigtool.csk & sigtool.d , right !?) from the 3 .csi, and put them in the build.xml folder.
But when I launch 'ant load-device', I've got an error because ant can't find signing key ...

```
[exec] [ERROR]                     Cannot sign application - failed to find
       signing keys
```

Where should I put them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Succesful installation of 3 .cis files, which you have received from RIM. You should have 3 more files on the isntallable directory.

1. sigtool.csk
2. sigtool.db
3. sigtool.set

All three required for Blackberry code signing, verify and locate their presence in signing key installable folder.

Comment: I cant find the .csk/.db/.set files Im using a Mac :(