# Signing Blackberry application using Ant

Tags: blackberry, cordova, certificate

Hello I have built a blackberry application using the phonegap and ANT. I can successfully run the application over the simulator but when I tried to install on the phone but it dint install. I figured out that I need to sign the code. I have downloaded the three certificates which i have got through mail and installed them successfully. Now I need to know how can I sign the code and make a build. Any help? I am using phonegap + Ant. Not eclipse plugin.

Thank you

Comment: Searching "+blackberry +sign" I see a few duplicates of this question on stack overflow, at least one specifically about phonegap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893030/sign-blackberry-application-with-phonegap-ant-tool

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Blackberry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/)

That will give you a set of Ant task for blackberry specific task, including a "sigtool" task that can be used to sign your cod files.